# How to have Aurelia child routers with their own authorize step

Tags: authentication, authorization, aurelia, authorize

I have two child routers, one for admin access, and one for public access
The public access routes have an AuthorizeStep added and checks to see if the user is logged in.

The admin access uses different authentication so to check if an admin user is authenticated I need to do a different check.

My app.ts with the "parent" routes:

```
 configureRouter(config, router) {
    config.title = 'My site';
    config.addPipelineStep('authorize', AuthorizeStep);
    config.map([
      { route: '', redirect: 'Public' },
      { route: 'Public', moduleId: 'public/views/home', name:'public', title: 'Public Portal - Home' },
      { route: 'Admin', moduleId: 'admin/home', name:'admin', title: 'Admin - Home' }
    ]);

    this.router = router;
  }
}
```

The public child router looks something like:

```
configureRouter(config, router) {
    config.map([
        { route: '', moduleId: './home', name: 'home', title: 'Home', auth: true },
        { route: 'login', moduleId: './login', name: 'login', title: 'Login' },
        { route: 'page2/:id', moduleId: './page2', name: 'page2', title: 'Page 2', auth: true }
    ]);

    this.router = router;
 }
```

Where home and page 2 routes are authenticated.

The admin child router looks something like:

```
configureRouter(config, router) {
        config.map([
            { route: 'page1', moduleId: './page1/home', name: 'page1', title: 'page 1', auth: true },
            { route: 'page2', moduleId: './page2/home', name: 'page2', title: 'page 2', auth: true }
        ]);

        this.router = router;
  }
```

With only authenticated routes. 
I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
configureRouter(config, router) {
        config.addPipelineStep('authorize', AdminAuthorizeStep);
        config.map([
            { route: 'page1', moduleId: './page1/home', name: 'page1', title: 'page 1', auth: true },
            { route: 'page2', moduleId: './page2/home', name: 'page2', title: 'page 2', auth: true }
        ]);

        this.router = router;
  }
```

Where the addPipelineStep occurs on the child router rather than the parent router, but this doesn't work, or I haven't been able to get this working, is it even possible? Or am I only able to have one AuthorizeStep and handle logic inside that to determine if its an admin or public user accessing the route?

Comment: Define "doesn't work",

Comment: the page doesn't render at all, just a blank page, seems as if the routing breaks (no error in console)

Comment: Provided you're got your logging settings set to Development mode - there's no way it should fail without an error in the console

Comment: I've added: 
`aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging()`

And I still don't get any error in the console, (I do get all the debug messages as I did before)

Comment: Where is `AdminAuthorizeStep` defined?

Comment: brought in through require, looks like:

`export class AdminAuthorizeStep {
  run(routingContext, next) {
    var isAuthenticated = sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken') != null;

    var loginRoute = 'admin/login';

    if (routingContext.getAllInstructions().some(i => i.config.auth)) {
        if (!isAuthenticated) {
          //perform admin authentication
          return next.cancel();
        }
    }

    return next();
  }
}`

Comment: using the same approach on the parent router and works fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142822/discussion-between-mattjes-and-thebluefox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is not possible for child routers. In aurelia-router.js:

```
if (pipelineSteps.length) {
  if (!router.isRoot) {
    throw new Error('Pipeline steps can only be added to the root router');
  }
...
```

And I do get the error in my console:
`ERROR [app-router] Error: Pipeline steps can only be added to the root router`

Comment: thanks for your response. In the end, to get what I needed I handled all logic for public and admin access in the one AuthorizeStep. I essentially check the route which is being accessed, then determine the authorisation strategy based on that.